# Why Add button in EFS doesn't exists?

Tags: windows, encrypting-file-system

I am trying to enable EFS on a folder and add some others users to access it too. but the Add button doesn't exist on the place it should be. I want to know what is the reason for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a user/key to a single encrypted file only, *not* on a entire directory. This depend on how EFS works. So, the "add" button will be present only when editing single file properties.

Comment: That's kind of disappointing for EFS. Do you know a way to do such a thing on a directory ?
btw, thank you @shodanshok.

Comment: Unfortunately, no workaround exist for apply directory-wide encryption policies with EFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to add a user to a directory:

```
 cipher ".\YourFolder" /adduser Dom\TestUser /s
```